# How to search by DLL in project NuGet Packages?

Tags: .net, dependencies, nuget

I need to see from which package some DLLs come from and I don't know if there is a straight forward way to do so.

For example, in the image below, is there a way to search for `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`  and find that it comes from `AspNetCore.HealthChecks.Uris`?

[image]

I am working with .NET 6 in VS 2022, but I am open to using other tools, I am just looking for a way to do this search.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that I am able to track down the source NuGet of a specific DLL by searching for that DLL in the dependencies of the other NuGets until reaching the root one in the *<project_name>.deps.json* file from the `/bin/Debug/<platform>` folder.

for example I am finding Microsoft.Extensions.Logging as part of Microsoft.Extensions.Http

[image]

and then Microsoft.Extensions.Http as part of AspNetCore.HealthChecks.Uris

[image]

It's a bit difficult, but it's the best way I've found so far.